# How do I use JQuery to build link using an HTML data- attribute?

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to do a project for my boss that is a little over my head, and hoping you can help me out.  I have read all the previous questions that looked relevant, but I don't think any are quite on point ... or if they are, I don't understand the answers.

I am working with a webpage format that defines this attribute:
    `data-action="sample-campaign"`

Further down the page, I need to generate a link that is based on that variable.  Like:
    `http://sum.org/a/sample-campaign/?sub=link`

I assume there is just a tiny bit of JQuery magic I need here? But I am too much of a JQuery beginner to figure it out on my own.  Help?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you post more html

Comment: I could ... can you tell me which parts will be useful?  I can't post the entire source code, and am not sure what will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a little example: http://jsfiddle.net/6zhqmpup/3/

```
<div data-action="sample-campaign">hello world</div>

var el = $('[data-action]');
var str = 'http://sum.org/a/'+el.data("action")+'/?sub=link';

el.html('<a href="' + str + '">' + str + '</a>');
```

or if you have multiple elements with the `data-action` attribute http://jsfiddle.net/6zhqmpup/4/

```
<div data-action="sample-campaign">hello world</div>
<div data-action="xxx-xxx">xxx</div>
<div data-action="yyy-yyy-yyyy">xxx</div>

$('[data-action]').each(function(e){
    var str = 'http://sum.org/a/' + $(this).data('action') + '/?sub=link';
    $(this).html('<a href="' + str + '">' + str + '</a>');

});
```